# What does new Foo(bar) {public void baz(){....} }; mean in Java?

Tags: java, android, methods, instantiation, sample

I'm trying to understand the NavigationDrawer sample for the Android SDK and I met this:

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

When do these methods get called, right after the instantiation? I'm not familiar with this syntax. How does this work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is an anonymous inner class. Given an interface or class Foo with 0 or more abstract methods, you can use:

```
Foo blech=new Foo(){
    void bar(int baz){
        System.out.println("quux");
    }
}
```

to create an instance of Foo with methods implemented or overridden. All abstract methods(of which there may be 0) will need to be implemented in the braces. The constructor is still called as usual and parameters can be passed in the parentheses.

These are often used for listeners or other objects that need to be run and should specify different actions without creating new classes extending or implementing them.

These will compile down to `[Outer Class]$[Number].class`, once for each anonymous inner class used in the code, even if any are never reached or any are used multiple times

Comment: Yes, I had completely misunderstood this part. They are used in Android all the time, I just didn't even think about that when it came to a toggle, it's more used in listeners. The drawer is either closed or open, so does that mean that even in the first time the code runs one of those is going to run, what about the first time the code runs, is it considered open or closed?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mess, I guess I'm gonna close this and open a new one, this follow-up is actually more what was confusing me than the use of an anonymous inner class, which is quite common.

Comment: @Tom: "The drawer is either closed or open, so does that mean that even in the first time the code runs one of those is going to run" -- that behavior is undocumented and therefore could vary over time. "what about the first time the code runs, is it considered open or closed?" -- this too is undocumented. You are welcome to run some test code to see what the current behavior is, but bear in mind that the behavior could conceivably change in some update to `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: I wish I could promote your comment to an answer then I would edit my question. I've been trying to learn Android for the last 10 days or so and I must say that all the time I bump into the "documentation is horrible" problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override methods of a class for one specific instance by using that syntax. A very common usage is indeed Listeners or Handlers (eg: MouseListener, KeyListener, etc...).

This results in an anonymous subclass of the class you are extending. The subclass has no name. And is compiled into `WrapperClass$0`, `WrapperClass$1` and so on...